# gradient coloring of an object

Tags: xna-4.0, color

I have an object(FBX format) in my project, it's a line drawn in 3D max. I want to color the line in XNA so that the color starts from a specific RGB color in both the start and end points of the line and finish in a specific RGB color.(e.x., from (255,255,255) to (128,128,128). Something like gradient coloring of an object. I need to do that programmatically, since later in my code I have to change these two specific colors a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In 3DS Max, select your line geometry and apply the `VertexPaint` modifier to it. This way you can paint individual vertices with the color of your choice, although I don't know if FBX format supports exporting this information.

If you need to change the color later, paint one end in pure white and the other in a middle gray; then, inside your code, change the `DiffuseColor` of your `BasicEffect` to achieve the desired tinting.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Gradient_skybox.php) article talks about gradient shaders:

You might be able to adapt that to shade your model (draw it with the shader) instead of the skybox.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I could use the shader for an object like a magnet with 3 meshes and it works. however I want to use that for only a line (an FBX object) with only one mesh and it seems all the  line has a equal color :(